# Wmi EventWatcher missing events - fix?

Tags: c#, printing, wmi

I'm trying to monitor our server and need to catch the `__InstanceCreationEvent` to get a notification whenever a `Win32_PrintJob` has been created. For this I try to use a `ManagementEventWatcher` which works almost good but the Watcher misses some PrintJob creations.

```
ManagementEventWatcher watcher = 
                    new ManagementEventWatcher(Server.Name + @"\root\cimv2",
                    "Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 
                    Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PrintJob'");

watcher.EventArrived += PrintJobCreated;
watcher.Start();
```

Whenever a very short/little PrintJob is created e.g. a test page, I dont get the creation event all the time. I have no idea but I guess it's because the PrintJob is done just before the 1 second timer runs out is it possible?

However. Is there a way to receive 100% of all `PrintJob` creations?

Or is it event better to use another mechanism than a WMI-watcher?

**Update**

I've tried to change `within` to `0.1` which works much better, but does 100ms make sense here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All intrinsic events (like __InstanceCreationEvent) in WMI makes use of polling to detect changes - there is always a chance that a particularly short event will be missed. By decreasing the polling interval you will definitely improve the detection rate however there's absolutely no guarantees.

Also keep in mind that WMI polling queries consume lots of CPU resources, you don't mention your environment however in general the more print queues you are going to monitor the more CPU utilization you'll see. If you increase the polling rate the effect will be magnified. This in turn could lead to more missed events etc.

If you absolutely need accuracy you could look at the the [FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextPrinterChangeNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API functions however it's a bit more complex to implement than your WMI solution. There's some guidance at [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51085/Monitor-jobs-in-a-printer-queue-NET) on how to make it work in .NET/C#.

Comment: I know the Win32 api. normally i'm a c++ dev and i'm trying to rewrite my program in c# for learning purposes